How to deal as a PhD student with a working colleague who is doing private business during working hours
I am new to a small team (4-5 people) at a research group. Naturally, I depend on others showing me how many things work at the office (it is my first experience working at a university after all).
However, the professor as well as most of my colleagues decided to work from home (which means I am usually alone at the office). Sometimes, one of the other PhD students is around. However, since the professor is not at the office, he uses the time to do private business and trade cryptocurrency in the research lab. This side business is a business he founded with his friends; it is not related to our research. Usually I would not mind, since it is none of my business, but it bothers me for two reasons:

Actually, since I am new to the working group, I would expect him to explain to me the state of his research and how the methods that he uses work, so that we can collaborate (we share some projects together and, after all, I think this is what a working group is for)
This student is paid by the tax money of my fellow citizens. And he uses the infrastructure (office, building, etc.) to conduct his own business. I think this is not fair.

Also, when I try to have some scientific discussions he blocks it off as he is either busy with his own research or with his side business.
I don't want to be the one who goes to the professor and tells her what other students are doing. However, I want a working atmosphere where people actually do research and not private business. Also, I really don't want to dictate other PhD students what to do with their time. Is there any good way to handle this?

The answers until now suggest that it is only something between the student and the professor. But I disagree. Scientific work has always been done together. It cannot be expected from newcomers to exactly know how to do specific scientific research if no one ever showed them how to do it. (And being a student and being a PhD student are still two different things.) Usually in labs you are being taught how the simplest microscope works. Why should it be different with methods that work solely on a computer?
In many books and dissertations the authors thank their coworkers and supervisors for 'fruitful discussions'. And also if those words are often spoken out of politeness, I'd say it is one of the main pillars of scientific research. As one professor recently said in an interview (here: 34:30):

Unfortunately, it is often forgotten that science is a social endeavour. Because often people think of the big intellectuals when they think about science, who sit at their desk and crank out their monographs [...]. However, this is only a part of what it means to do science, but which of course in the public opinion replaces (German: übertünchen) what science really is. Namely, a cooperative undertaking."


"Wissenschaft ist eine soziale Praxis. Das wird leider sehr oft vergessen, weil oft denkt man bei Wissenschaft an die großen Intellektuellen in ihren Schreibstuben, die irgendwelche Monographien raushauen alle paar Jahre. Das ist wirklich nur ein Randsegment der Wissenschaft, das aber natürlich in der öffentlichen Wahrnehmung übertüncht was eigentlich die wissenschaftliche Praxis ist. Das ist ein kooperatives Unternehmen."

When it is not written on other publications, monographs, etc. it is because it is taken for granted.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Your edit seems like more of an answer than an edit; consider posting it as such (self-answering your own question is perfectly okay). Also: did the professor assign this student as your mentor or partner? If not, I'm having trouble understanding why you are focusing your outrage on them, rather than on the others who don't even set foot in the building.

@cag51 The student made calculations and simulations in the last 2-3 years which I shall use in my PhD work. During the team meetings I said it would be nice to meet as a group, but this suggestion was ignored multiple times. I even had a meeting with the HR department and my supervisor where I said the same. The reaction was that HR asked me why I am still at the university if I didn't like it (they basically asked me to leave).

What country? In the US, PhD students aren't usually paid or treated as full-time employee with set working hours, and they're often charged student fees to pay for those facilities you mentioned (building, internet, etc). Policing their activity during "working hours" is not your place. However, their research likely belongs to the professor or the university, and you should be able to access it. Sometimes more senior lab members are tasked with training newer ones, but not always. If that's something you feel you need, you could raise that specific question with the professor.

We are being paid and we have working contracts. And as I see it we earn quite well compared to the average income in the country we live in (of course that's subjective kind of). I also think we earn more than the average PhD student elsewhere as our professor is really interested in having us not worrying about money during our PhD time.


since it is none of my business

It's none of your business. Leave it alone.

I would expect him to explain to me the state of his research and how the methods work

Are you asking questions? If not, ask questions. If you need help, ask for help. If you're unable to get the help you need, that is something that is your business and worth raising with your professor.
If the other student is not making progress on their research, this will be evident to the professor over time. Perhaps they're putting in more productive hours at other times of the day, on weekends, etc. In any event, it's not necessary to police "time on task" during standard business hours to track progress, and if the student falls behind it's ultimately their own research that suffers. It's not your business.

+1 Indeed, it's between the other student and their professor.

+1. And might add, as you said youre new to the group, there can be many reasons a colleague behaves like that, including personal problems. Be nice.

This.  I would add that, if I were the professor and you came complain about it to me, I would tell you to mind your own business, even though I would also talk to the other student.

This is too strongly stated. OP already acknowledged all the reasons for them to put up with it and say nothing. It is reasonable to "want a working atmosphere where people actually do research and not private business."

@toby544 It's not reasonable for OP to expect to be helped without asking questions or asking for help.

@BryanKrause Oh, I have been asking for help multiple times

@ThoRe That isn't mentioned in your question and you indicated in a comment elsewhere that you haven't been but are expecting people to train you anyways. If your real problem is that you are asking questions and they are not getting answered, you should write your question about that and not this private business.

@BryanKrause In the question I mentioned 'scientific discussions'. For what reason should I engage in scientific discussions if they don't help me. They help to answer a lot more questions than if I was to try to think of each and every question on my own. Besides that, yes for certain things I indeed expect a training without me explicitly asking for it. For example, when I have to use specific software, which is being used for many years already at the institute. Why should I constantly ask for the bare minimum?

@ThoRe You shouldn't constantly ask, you should do your best to learn on your own. In the best case scenario, other PhD students are working on their own thesis. They are not there to merely help with yours. In my experience, scientific discussions happen a) when people ask me questions, and b) in more structured settings like journal clubs, lab meetings, etc.

@BryanKrause Of course, nobody is legally bound to help anyone at their work. But what is the point of a working group if the younger members cannot profit from the experience of the elder ones. It should be an honour for every team member of every group to be open for questions of newcomers. Furthermore, I can tell you that questions in our group meeting are not very welcome and more or less ignored.

@ThoRe Then those are the problems to ask about resolving: that questions in group meetings are not welcome and are ignored. Not this one student who you perceive as working on an outside project.

@BryanKrause Both problems exist, and both of them should be resolved. I think you underestimate the importance of a working atmosphere, where I can go at anytime to a colleague and ask him questions, not worrying about if he is currently doing something that has nothing to do with science or work related to the working group. Group meetings are once every two weeks, being able to work together or to not work together affects every day.

@ThoRe Why does it matter if he's doing something science related or not when you ask a question? See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem You can assert that both of these things are problems; my answer and several other answers here are telling you that one of them is not your problem. In the Stack Exchange model, we should answer the question asked, not a separate question about a different problem that is not the one you asked about in your original post.

It matters. Because, when he does science related work, he just can say: "Hey, sorry I am busy with this problem right now. Come here and take a look at it. Have you ever heart of this problem? I am trying to solve it for several days already..." If he does not do science related work, he will just say: "Hey. Look at that xyz currency/stock exchange/... Do you know how much I have invested in this and that? Have you already bought NFTs?..." In the first case I learn something, in the second case I don't learn anything (except for trading which I am not interested in)

@ThoRe The more you stick to this argument, the more you convince me that you are likely the bigger problem here than your colleague. I've said all I can say. I'm trying to help you, but if you're just here looking for someone to support "your side" you've come to the wrong place. Ask questions here when you plan to use the answers, not when you already know the answer you want.

Pretend that your team has one fewer member and that person is on a different team.   Just because they are in the office doesn't mean anything.   Ask questions of the others that are working from home if you need help and that person won't help you.

@JasonGoemaat He made calculations (very complicated ones) that I need for my thesis. I cannot simply ignore him.

@ThoRe Is the methodology for those calculations written down someplace? (in a publication, perhaps?) What specific questions do you have about the calculations? Have you asked those specific questions? What happened when you asked those questions? What background knowledge is necessary to understand them? What efforts have you made to obtain that background knowledge besides existing in the lab and waiting for learning to happen?

It is absolutely not your business how other people use their time. The other PhD student owes you absolutely nothing. They're not your advisor, nor are you entitled to their time, or entitled to get any of your questions answered— they're not your babysitter, they're not paid to teach you, and they're certainly not paid to work on any specific time schedule. Academic research isn't a job where you clock in and clock out according to a schedule— it has flexibility, and people use that.
Stop focusing on spying on other people and start focusing on getting results yourself.

+1 To this. I once had a new PhD student track me down on my lunch break to ask questions (because I asked not to be interrupted during work before a deadline- but clearly I wasn't working during lunch!). They burned through the groups' collective goodwill pretty fast with similar stunts.

There is middle way between "baby sitting" and completely turning someone down. Have you never learned from elder working colleagues?

@ThoRe You have to gauge the style of work. There are very collaborative groups and groups where people are more independent. Maybe the research culture of the group does not suit you. That can happen. But you do not get to dictate your desired culture onto a group you just joined.

@ThoRe You have so far rejected all advice on how to communicate and collaborate with your colleagues, and while none of us witnessed your interactions with the group, it doesn't speak well for the case you're making.

@ThoRe You give arguments why it would be nice if the other PhD student acted differently. And you're probably right about this. But this doesn't mean that you have any right to this. They are not like this and you've got to accept that.

This answer is not correct. Members of a research group are certainly entitled to have many of their research related questions answered by other more experienced group members. A collaborative research environment is the standard in academia. This has very little to do with 'babysitting'.

@CaptainEmacs This is true. The issue has been there for around 9 months already. And so far I haven't complained about it for the exact reason you give. But people tend to forget how important elder team members are. It is simply not possible to invent everything from scratch what the working group has discovered over the last 5 or so years. Not to mention that everybody can benefit from each other's different backgrounds.

@ThoRe As I say - ask your PI for help. They can decide what the best way forward is. You do not get a say in how people are to help you - maybe the person in the lab is the wrong one to do so. Just because they happen to share the office with you, they do not become your go-to address. Respect their working style.

It could depend on the country, but if this is happening in Germany, one could argue that one PhD student might actually owe something to another (not much but also not nothing). In that case, both of them are likely employed by the State, meaning that the taxes one pays are funding the activities of another. As a taxpayer, the author has a legitimate reason to be concerned about the potential misuse of public funds.

@user2705196 Members of a research group are ... entitled ... No, they are not. Much also depends on in which way and how often the person requests (requires?) advice, and also if it is an only one way route, whether the other person can be expected to be a mentor (e.g. a postdoc). The other person is a PhD student. They do not owe OP mentorship. Maybe also OP would need a whole group to support them, and now everything falls on the one person that happens to sit in the office. I can imagine someone resenting having to do the full initiation of a new group member on their own.

"spying on other people" is surely not what the OP is doing by hearing phone calls that are in the same room.

-1 for "Stop focusing on spying on other people". This is uncalled for. The OP is not focused on spying on people. To make this a helpful and proper Stack Exchange answer post, you should remove this misleading item. One can not stop doing what one is not doing. Ditto for "start focusing..."

"I want a working atmosphere" - Covid has done a lot of damage to the tradition of sitting together and sweating together. Some people are more productive at home, others less so. And this also changed the social pressure of mutual "supervision". Results have become more important than "being seen to be doing work", or, in short "busywork".
You have no idea how productive your fellow student is. Some people do in two days what others need weeks for (definitely not an exaggeration, especially in theoretical/programming fields!). As a prof, I would give such people as much leeway as I can muster.
In short, it is not your business to interfere in. If you need something concrete from them, ask. If you do not get the suitable support, ask your supervisor; they are paid to solve this.

I think this is an important point not mentioned in the other answers. But I think we lost much more than just "sitting and sweating" together. A lot of upcoming PhD students who now prefer to work from home don't even have a baseline of working from a bustling, collaborative lab, as they never had the opportunity. I think the saddest consequence is that indeed some people now need weeks for tasks their labmates could've thought them in a matter of days.

@penelope I guess in 30 years or so from today, the powers that be will realize that. Management fads are more tenacious than bedbugs.

I understand and agree all the other answers, but I want to add the following: it sounds as if your expectations of the lab/working environment do not match with reality. And, going by what you write, it is implied that maybe you are not as successful/productive as you can be because you don’t have as much interaction as you’d expected. Now these things are something you can discuss with your supervisor, but then make sure you have your talking points straight. And from what I gather they are: you miss support and supervision. What is the best way forward? Maybe your supervisor expects you to find out more stuff independently. Maybe they never told the other student to help you here and there. The point is, you don’t know. So approach the conversation from this angle, about your progress and your output and happiness at work. Then listen very carefully to what you cl get back and ask yourself if you can prosper in the reality of this particular work place.

On the topic of expectations, it's worth thinking about what collaboration looks like in academia. Most of it is asynchronous with occasional meet-ups. It seems pretty common to meet with a supervisor for an hour every week or two.  Maybe hold a lab meeting for an hour once per week. Maybe chat with a colleague about a (very) active collaboration a couple times per week over coffee and have an occasional longer meeting every few weeks to talk through different stages. Asynchronously co-work on a manuscript leaving notes for one another. We work alone the rest of the time.

I feel this is the best answer. OP is focusing on the wrong problem - what their co-worker does or does not do while in office is not their issue, their issue is that they are expecting a vibrant lab culture whereas this group is either completely decoupled or used to pure remote collaboration. It's quite frankly not the other student's job to be the sole trainer of OP just because they are the only ones in office. This is something to bring up with the advisor, not what the other student is doing.

Partly the answer to this is going to depend on what country you are in,  because the legal and social status of a PhD student is quite different in different countries.
In some countries (notably many mainland European counties), a PhD student is an employee. Probably they have designated hours when they are "on the clock", and a set of written down duties,  which may or may not included helping more junior members of the lab.  In this case,  working on another business during office hours and failing to meet ones own duties is a breach of this contract.
However,  in most places a student is not an employee,  they are a student.  In fact,  legally speaking,  the student is employing the professor to provide skills and training.  The professor may only agree to provide these under certain conditions,  but that is between the professor and the student,  unless the student is being actively abusive to another indevidual.  Certainly the student may do whatever work they like whenever they like,  unless told otherwise. Look at it this way - if they decided to work from home like everyone else,  you'd be in an even worse place.
Now,  that is the official position.  These are the responsibilities people must observe.  That does mean that this is the optimal situation. A well functioning research team should be a collegial and collaborative place.  But you can't legislate for it,  it can only occur through long cultivation of the right culture.
So what can you do? Ignore the people telling you to be self sufficient.  If you are in a lab setting, such self-sufficiency is often more or less impossible.  The only person who definitely has any official responsibilities to you is your supervisor.  Go to them.  Say "I need help doing X",  "things are going okay,
but it is slow going because i can't find anything in the lab" . If they say "ask Y to help you", then,  any only then can you say "I asked Y, but they didn't want to help me" or maybe even "they said they were too busy doing Z to help me" if you are pushed.

Even in countries where the PhD student is an employee, they have flexibility and don't work by the clock. I work as a researcher in one of these countries and this is in my work contract. We have minimum amount of hours per week, but there is no such thing as designated hours to be "on the clock". Advising colleagues is, of course, encouraged in our department.

Contracts where we are have core hour and flexible hours  this generally means you can choose your own hours,  but these are expected to include 10-4. It's not particularly enforced,  and would probably only be called upon if an employee was not performing.

I know. I don't have core hours on my research contract and I doubt the phd students have it. Now I see that my comment sounded stronger than I intended, I didn't want to generalize, just sharing my experience in Norway. Sorry!

Some German research institute I know has moved away from core working hours per employee and now has core functional hours: hours in which a department or group has to have someone (typically not a PhD student) whom one can contact. OTOH (long ago, some other university) I've had employments contracts stating core hours that were not legally compatible with the assigned teaching tasks - and teaching the assigned practica had priority.

I work at a UK university, my contracts says I need to work 1650 h a year and that's about it. Of course most meetings are scheduled during core work hours and I am expected to attend, plus I am middle aged, but if the weekly meetings with the supervisor/remote collaborators is the only time a PhD students sees daylight, that is OK as long as everything else works.

Let me state firstly that I completely do not want to take the side of someone like your colleague. But I get a feeling that you're being a bit too hasty with wanting to complain. Your motivations are from a perspective of academic integrity which is admirable in isolation.
But consider that you would be injecting yourself into a matter completely between the other student and the supervisor. You can't possibly know the whole picture when you complain - resulting in possibly serious repercussions for your colleague, who could possibly be fulfilling all the demands of your supervisor till your complaint.

Also, when I try to have some scientific discussions he blocks it

This is the only thing you can reasonably complain about, if and only if it's his responsibility to show you the ropes of how things work in the lab. If it isn't, it's your supervisor's responsibility to figure out that their funding is being used irresponsibly.

However, I want a working atmosphere where people actually do research

But if their output is sufficient according to the supervisor, it's not their responsibility to give you one. It's frustrating but it's ultimately not something they care about, and it falls on the supervisor and not you to deal with it during hiring and contract negotiations.

By this post, as well as your other posts and comments, it seems you have a very specific idea in mind of what the PhD/academic experience should be.
I will tell you as I had to tell my young children on the playground, while it would be nice if they did, other kids have no obligation to play with you or share their toys. In the same way, forcing your senior colleagues to interact with you will not foster a sense of comradery, it will likely (as may already be happening) annoy them and lead to further avoidance.
Because you have placed such high value on this aspect, you should seek out a different research group with a dynamic that meets your expectations. The warning I would issue with that approach is that the group dynamic is often a function of the members, so while you may join a group that suits your needs at the time, the dynamic may change as more senior members leave and newer ones join. Though presumably as you become a more senior member, you can become more proactive in setting the tone for day-to-day activities.

Even though I got your idea, the university is not a playground.

@ThoRe metaphor: "a figure of speech in which a word or phrase is applied to an object or action to which it is not literally applicable"; "a thing regarded as representative or symbolic of something else, especially something abstract"

I know what a metaphor is. Anyway, thanks for the clarification. My point is, at the playground every kid has its own toys and can decide whether or not to share them. Contrary, at the university money is involved and working contracts. In one document it is even stated that as a new PhD student training will be provided to have a firm knowledge of the methods being used at the institute. None of this has been done in the first 9 months (even though I must admit it is not the primary duty of the other PhD student). What is the point of being in a working group if you can't talk about science

@Trunk the group dynamic is a function of the members. The PI sets expectations but cannot dictate to a group member to be more outgoing or to befriend anyone. The PI can foster an environment where certain behavior is encouraged, but outside of punishing behavior that is strictly forbidden (e.g. discrimination), they cannot enforce beyond that. It seems the OP would like a more collegial and collaborative environment and what he got was a group of self-motivated introverts.

@ThoRe "not the primary duty of the other PhD student", it is likely not any nth level of duty of the other PhD student unless they were instructed by the advisor directly to do so as long as it falls within the allowable guidelines of expectations of that University. Additionally, you cannot force people to talk science, or even talk to you at all in the working environment beyond specific times/requirements where they would need to do so, e.g. seminar, group meetings, defense, questions about safety, etc... Ultimately you need to talk to your advisor about having your training needs met.

@ThoRe "Training will be provided" - if these are the words in your contract, and you insist on them being literally enacted, do ask your PI. It's their job. Not the other student's. Frankly, it seems you are in the wrong group for your tastes.

I will only address this aspect of your question (which the other answers have mostly ignored), that this other student is using their time at the office to work on "private business"
Depending on the local culture and policies (i.e. of the group, institute, university, or country), this can range from totally acceptable to totally unacceptable.  In general, academia is quite relaxed on these matters, emphasizing results rather than working hours. This is especially true in the US, which explains the perspective of the other answers here.
But not everywhere is so informal. For example, in industry, "private business" during working hours is usually banned. Indeed, using your work time and the company computer to do work for another company or your own startup idea, is usually grounds for being fired.  Academic jobs in some places (e.g. Europe) tend to have more formal working contracts, like those in industry (although the extent to which people actually take this seriously depends heavily on the particular institute or research group).
If you seriously suspect that this student is doing something inappropriate, and that your supervisor does not already know about it, then you can politely mention this to your supervisor, and let them handle it.
I stress that this has nothing to do with the "working environment" aspect of your question, to which I defer to the other answers.  But if you genuinely believe this other student is doing something wrong or illegal, then just report it.

You should warn OP that if it turns out not to be illegal or they have simply a different day cycle (yes, some people prefer to do research at night where nobody disturbs them), they could get a stain they will not get rid of. They should be better very sure that they are not missing something from the picture. Of course, if the other person is outright doing criminal things, this is a different story.

I would expect your university, like all universities, has a code of conduct, check with your HR or graduate service office about your code of conduct and policies regarding private consulting, part-time work for PhD, and using University resources for private business, it should be very clear this trading crypto on University time and devices is in preach of Policy or Code of conduct. At my university PhD students are basically treated as staff and this would be a breach of the code of conduct without a doubt!
Also, ask yourself, what is your legal liability? Is the crypto trading they are conducting even legal in your country? Are you liable or in breach of policy for not reporting a colleague for conducting illegal activities utilising University resources?
In regards to the collaborative working culture (or lack of) in your lab, I would recommend leaving ASAP. You sound like you are very interested in learning and research, so I recommend finding a lab with a collaborative supportive culture, and do you due diligence in finding such a lab, and don't join unless there is evidence of an environment and culture you value.
Also, if you are in an industry that has a high employment rate, skip the PhD and move into industry, 3 years experience in industry is worth more than a PhD in many industries.
If you have your heart set on being an academic, good luck! but I'd skip it, after doing a PhD and working for 10 years I have realised it was totally pointless, as the real work and innovation happens in industry.

Thank you for your kind answer. Like all universities we have a code of conduct. But (also probably similar to all universities) no one really cares as long as HR is not around. And as a PhD student I don't see it as my role to play the 'department police' at the institute. At least not to employees who have the same or higher position. Thank you again, for your kind suggestion to look out for other groups whose dynamics may suit me more.

@ThoRe "Look out for other groups" is what the majority of responses have told you in various ways. Do note that many places have moved to "work from home", though, sadly, so check the place out ahead of time.

@ThoRe If you think someone in your department is doing something wrong, possibly illegal, shouldn't you at least check with a superior  to alleviate your liability. It also raises some ethical and integrity issues for you, as a researcher all you have is your integrity and once compromised, your research will always be questioned. Ask yourself, where do you draw the line? how much wrongdoing or questionable activity will you witness until you are prepared to suffer the discomfort of taking action? Would you even press the fire alarm if there was a fire? What's your integrity worth?

In a PhD program, self-sufficiency is not just expected. It is essential. If you cannot independently manage your research, learn new techniques on your own, and drive your projects forward without constant supervision, then a PhD is not for you. Relying on another student, who is also navigating their own challenges, is unrealistic and unfair. This program demands a high level of autonomy, resilience, and self-motivation. If you find yourself struggling to meet these demands, it may be a clear indication that you are not suited for the rigorous and independent nature of PhD studies. Pursuing a PhD requires a relentless drive and the ability to overcome obstacles on your own. If you are not prepared to meet these standards, it is best to reconsider your path.

Yes. That is what professors also tell me a lot. However, I have a working contract. For me, such a contract implies that I have certain responsibilities but also certain rights. Responsibilities include that I finish my work in the given amount of time (in this case 3 years). But as in every good company I should get the suitable training so that I am actually capable of doing my job. And if there is no training, at least having someone to ask questions to should be the bare minimum. Why else should I be at the university?

@ThoRe Your advisor has a responsibility to offer you guidance. A PhD is still quite self-driven. What are you doing to drive your own work? As I've prompted you before: are you asking questions when you need training? If not, you're failing your own job.

@ThoRe You can turn that around. Why should a company employ you if you require so much training? If things are so easy that they can be trained then someone could spend that same time programming a computer to do the task, and the computer will be cheaper to employ than you. The only sane reason to employ humans is when the largest part of the job can't be trained.

I'm not sure whether or not I'm answering the question intended or a different question but most people have to schedule doctors appointments, do financial business, talk to insurance companies, other boring regular stuff, during business hours. They're not open after work. So officially it's not allowed but unofficially it's mandatory. Most people don't take a day off to schedule a doctors appointment. So if it's that kind of personal business, then yeah, of course it's done during work hours.

Of course. That's true. I also do it sometimes. What bothers me more, is that when we talk to each other (for example, if we go through some code together) he is constantly interupted by a call of some of his friends/wokring colleagues/family (I don't know as I don't speak his language), so that actually from an 1-hour meeting we effectively only work 20 minutes together. Not to mention that concentrated work is almost impossible when you are constantly interrupted. And that's the standard when working with him.

You need to become more self-sufficient. If working here is truly unfeasible due to a lack of support from that individual, it's time to consider a different topic.
I feel like you come across as someone people tend to avoid, making it difficult for others to thrive because of your judgmental and self-righteous attitude.
